# DNA to RNA Conversion using Python: How can I replace the text inputs without replacing/changing the inputs replaced beforehand?

Tags: python

So, I was just wondering how I could change DNA to RNA for a school project. G needs to be converted to C, A needs to be converted to U, T needs to be converted to A, and C needs to be converted to G. The problem here is that if I just add another 'replace' line, it will affect the previously converted G. Is there any easy workaround for this? And if there is, would you mind briefly explaining it?
Thanks.

```
def abc(a):
  DNA=str(a)
  newDNA=DNA.replace('G', 'C')
  new2DNA=newDNA.replace('A','U')
  new3DNA=new2DNA.replace('T','A')
  new4DNA=new3DNA.replace('C', 'G')
  print(new4DNA)
```

So, say I wanted to convert GATC to RNA.
If I put it through the code above, I will get GUAG, and not CUAG.

Comment: Maybe include a what you got vs what you expect too.

Comment: You want RNA as the output always?

Comment: Yes, just RNA as the output.

Comment: then just say `a = 'RNA'` right? inside of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DNA** to **MRNA**

```
def DNA_MRNA(inputDNA):
  MRNA = ''
  for code in inputDNA:
    if code == 'A':
      MRNA = MRNA + 'U'
    if code == 'C':
      MRNA = MRNA + 'G'
    if code == 'T':
      MRNA = MRNA + 'A'

  return MRNA

print(DNA_MRNA('ACTC'))
```

**DNA** to **TRNA**

```
def DNA_TRNA(inputDNA):
  TRNA = ''
  for code in inputDNA:
    if code == 'T':
      TRNA = TRNA + 'U'
    else:
      TRNA = TRNA + code

  return TRNA

print(DNA_TRNA('ACTC'))
```

Comment: I have a better One to answer your both Questions. Check the other answer.

Comment: The one provided here is completely fine, and it changes the variables without changing them back. It's also much simpler. However, I appreciate the effort you put in!

Answer (score 1):

```
def DNA_TO_RNA(inputDNA, typeRNA):


  if typeRNA.upper() not in ['MRNA', 'TRNA']:
      return 'inputRNA can have values MRNA adn TRNA. Please check inputRNA'
      exit()

  outputRNA = ''

  for code in inputDNA:

      if code.upper() not in ['A', 'C', 'T']:
          return 'DNA Sequence can only have A,C,T. Please check input DNA'
          exit()

      if typeRNA == 'MRNA':
          if code.upper() == 'A':
              outputRNA = outputRNA + 'U'
          elif code.upper() == 'C':
              outputRNA = outputRNA + 'G'
          elif code.upper() == 'T':
              outputRNA = outputRNA + 'A'
          else:
              outputRNA = outputRNA + code.upper()

      if typeRNA == 'TRNA':
          if code.upper() == 'T':
              outputRNA = outputRNA + 'U'
          else:
              outputRNA = outputRNA + code.upper()

  return outputRNA

print(DNA_TO_RNA('ACTC', 'MRNA'))  # UGAG
print(DNA_TO_RNA('ACTC', 'TRNA'))  # ACUC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dna_to_rna(dna):
    rna = ''
    for x in dna:
        if x == 'T':
            rna += 'U'
        else:
            rna += x
    return rna
print(dna_to_rna('AGCT'))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This does not differ in any meaningful way from the DNA to TRNA function provided in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
ref = {'G': 'C', 'A':'U', 'T':'A', 'C':'G'}

rna = ''

for char in dna:
    rna += ref[char]
```

Explanation,
consider `dna = 'GGATC'`. We initialize a new empty string as `rna`. Now we iterate through the characters of `dna`.

If the `char` is `G`, the we add `ref['G']` which is `'C'` to `rna`. Similarly for all characters in `dna`.

Comment: you can replace the entire function with this code and return the string ```rna``` at the end